# Javadoc @see tags in package-info

Tags: javadoc

We're working on a class project and using Javadocs to document our packages. package-info.java files are being used for the top-level package documentation, but we can't seem to use any @see tags to refer to other classes. Javadoc will constantly give 'reference not found' errors for all of them. Is there anything that must be done in order for the references to work? We already tried importing the referenced classes but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the full class name, including the package specifier.

```
@see com.stackoverflow.AwesomeClass
```

See Javadoc [spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#see)